# Cloudant does not not store object data sent via Bluemix "Data for iOS 8"

Tags: ios, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I am trying to store a simple object (a custom class that has two String properties) in a Cloudant DB from an iOS App. I am making use of the Bluemix iOS SDK, specifically "Data for iOS 8". So far I am trying to apply the samples for the Swift programming language from the IBM Bluemix documentation.

The code to store an object is from the tutorials and has been only slightly adapted, if at all. The code below is contained in a function that is called when a text field's edit is done.

```
var remoteStore:CDTStore!

    // initialize an instance of the IMFDataManager
    let manager:IMFDataManager = IMFDataManager.sharedInstance()
    let name = "pricingdb"

    var testData = TestData(firstName: "aaaa", lastName: "bbbbb")

    // Create remote store
    manager.remoteStore(name, completionHandler: { (createdStore:CDTStore!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if nil != error {
            //Handle error
        } else {
            remoteStore = createdStore
            println("Successfully created store: \(remoteStore.name)")
            // Register class with remote store
            remoteStore.mapper.setDataType("TestData", forClassName: NSStringFromClass(TestData.classForCoder()))

            // Actually save the object to Bluemix
            remoteStore.save(testData, completionHandler: { (savedObject:AnyObject!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
                if nil != error {
                    //Save was not successful, handler received an error
                    println("Error: \(error)")
                } else {
                    // Use the result
                    println("Saved revision: \(savedObject)")
                }
            })
        }
    })
```

The Cloudant database I want to store to exists. I can connect to the Datastore and the object is as well saved, the console output is:

```
HTTP_Status: 201
JSON Body: {
    id = 6dfde55449915faa92c471bd0ecd89d6;
    ok = 1;
    rev = "1-419dfa2a14026c4c18545723e8f990fa";
}
Saved revision: <pricingtester.TestData: 0x7f91f1c6e2f0>
```

However, when looking at the JSON Body above I would expect to see the object data in there and, even if it wouldn't/shouldn't show there, I would expect to see it in the database entry that was created. But the corresponding database entry when checking the Cloudant dashboard is as follows:

```
{
  "_id": "6dfde55449915faa92c471bd0ecd89d6",
  "_rev": "1-419dfa2a14026c4c18545723e8f990fa",
  "@datatype": "TestData"
}
```

What could I be missing?

A related question came up:
In the code above, the store is always created. If it exists, it is not recreated, but a reference to that store is made. If I know the store exists, which it does, how can I obtain a reference to that store without trying to first create it?

Comment: Hey -- it would be helpful if you could you show us some code context here. Something has clearly been written, but the body is empty, bar the @datatype field which is the hall mark of the object/document mapper. Happy to take a look at your code if you can share it.

Comment: Thanks for having a look. I added the code and hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you provide the source code for the TestData class?  For swift classes, String must currently use the NSString (ObjC) instead of the Swift String (e.g. var make:NSString)

Comment: Yes, that's it! My properties were strings (i.e. var make:String). Once NSString was used all items were neatly written to the Cloudant DB. The documentation states that NSString (or NSDate) must be used, but for me that was easy to overlook...